# why is clock stretching required in I2C

Tags: embedded, i2c

Clock stretching is used to slow down the  master in I2C.. If Slave device is I2C Based, then it means it can work in 100KHZ according to the standard.

My confusion is what is the need of clock stretching, when the clock is already 100KHz in Master and slave?

Please provide an example for this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The need of clock stretching because the Slave may is not able to received  from the Master or the Slave require additional time for process the received data.

Many Slave device is low cost device that don't have good buffer system, need long time read of slow memory and use clock stretching to prevent Overflow.

It is a cheap speed control system (compare as more complex async connections),safe and simple.

It also as some low cost devices CPU can not working on I2C when working on a busy task, For example a sensor may require interrupt and hold the clock line low, after sensor internal jobs done, the sensor will goes high and send the data under normal speed.

Ref: http://cache.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/app_note/AN4481.pdf P.12

Comment: Excellent Reference.. Can you please help me to resolve the confusion of how can the slave pull the SCL low, as the GPIO is input in the slave..

Comment: As SCL connected to GPIO with pull-up resistor,  set GPIO to High make SCL low, and the Master will detected the SCL line Low and become suspend and wait.

Comment: Do you mean setting GPIO to low

Comment: Set GPIO to High become SCL to Low (push to Ground)

Comment: To make SCL to high, We need to set GPIO to Low? I am not an expert on this.. Trying to understand

Comment: @md.jamal both master and slave should be using `open drain` (comparable to the older `open collector`) outputs which only drive low.  If neither is driving the line low, the pullup resistor brings it high.  This is a very simple way of making a shared signal on which any one of two (or more) device may either receive or transmit.

Comment: Thanks.. I now understood why there are using open drain instead of pull-up resistors...

Comment: @md.jamal Open Drain outputs are being used *with* pull-up resistors, not *instead of* them.  What the Open Drain outputs are being used "instead of" is "push pull" outputs or various other terms indicating that they drive actively in both low and high directions, and not only low as open drain outputs do.